# Where is the node.js file in the stack trace located?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js

Obviously, I'm pretty new to node.js. I'm attempting to debug a node.js application and I see node.js in the stack trace.

I would like to put some `sys.puts` calls in there, but I cannot locate the node.js that is being run by my server.

Is there a way to tell where node.js is located? Is there an equivalent to Ruby's `__FILE__` in node?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: `__FILE__` gives you the path of the current file. Node.js has `__filename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hidden in the source together with C++ sources and headers at **<node-installation>/src/node.js**.

You can't modify **node.js** and expect changes to have a direct effect. After a change you have to rebuild with **make**. You also can't do many things, for example you have to use **process.stdout.write()** instead of **sys.print()**.

Good luck!